# Ubuntu 14.04LTS - Random beep from system speaker

Tags: 14.04, sound, system, speakers

My internal speaker (mainboard) sometimes does a beep.
This seems to happen randomly. Sometimes it happens every few minutes, sometimes it is quiet for hours.
There seems to be no specific event triggering it.

I already tried everything i could find without success:

- sudo modprobe -r pcspkr / blacklist pcspk
- blacklist snd_pcsp
- xset b off
- hdparm -B 255
- temperatures are OK

It doesn't happen in Windows so I guess its not a general (BIOS) problem.

Does anyone else have an idea what i could try?
Otherwise I will have to unplug the internal speaker.

Cheers.

Comment: The same beep as on startup POST? A system sound?

Comment: Yes. A system beep from the internal speaker.  I unplugged it by now. I guess it came from the BIOS for some unknown reason.